# java file gets broken in intellij everytime i close the program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on a small project for a java course in IntelliJ

[image: userrepo working]

everything is good untill i close the program. after i open it it looks like this

[image: userrepo not working]

to fix it i need to go into the file explorer, add a s to the name or something, which will change the name into intellij too and then it reads it and i have to rename it back from intellij to UserRepository and all good after. Until i exit the program again.. and its a loop

Comment: Please check that file is not added as pattern in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types - java class"

Comment: @y.bedrov it's not , the hasbang patterns is empty

Comment: Is file name pattern is also empty? Do you have "Override file type" option available in file context menu?

Comment: Is it possible that something in your build system (or even IDEA project configuration) is misconfigured to write class files to `src/main/java/` instead of inside `target/`?

Comment: @y.bedrov , right click remove file override was or something like that was available on right click, i have clicked it now its back to normal. Thanks alot, you could submit the same answer and i can tick it as the winning one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems file was added as a pattern to "File Types - Java class". You may use  "Revert File type Override" option available in file context menu to restore defaults.